# Is there a html reporter to use with jest-cucumber which shows all the Gherkin annotations on report

Tags: jestjs, cucumberjs

I have started using **jest-cucumber** (https://github.com/bencompton/jest-cucumber) for automating my ReactJS app.

I have tried these reporters with the framework: https://github.com/jest-community/awesome-jest#reporters but I'm not able to see Gherkin steps on the report. 
All reports show the test case level details.

I tried to use cucumber-html-reporter https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter but unable to use it with jest-cucumber.

Can you suggest any good library which can report the Gherkin annotations step by step which will look like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with cucumber-html-reporter and jest-cucumber version 2.0.12. Please check the issue #27 of jest-cucumber: https://github.com/bencompton/jest-cucumber/issues/27.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Let me try this at office today. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to be followed:

1) Install  jest-cucumber with version **v2.0.12** that supports reporting. During this writeup this version was not available as stable version of npm. You need to specifically give the version number when installing this.

2) Add below paramter in jest config to specify the report storage location. The jest-cucumber outputs a json file.

`reporters: [
    "default",
    [
      "./node_modules/jest-cucumber/dist/src/reporter", //This is the default path
      {
        formatter: "json",
        path: "./tests/integration-test-results/test-report.json" //specific path
      }
    ]
  ]`

3) Create a index.js file for cucumber-html-report conf and mention the location of above created json file and output when the html file need to be placed. For more info, refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter

4) Create package.json command as shown below for ease of use so that once the BDD test completes,  the report is automatically generated and displayed.

```
"test-bdd": "jest --config=jest-cucumber.config.js && node ./cucumber-report-config.js"
```

5) Run: `npm run test-bdd`